# constexpr static template function: g++ error is a warning on clang

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, function-templates, storage-class-specifier

Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int I>
constexpr int f() { return I * f<I-1>(); }

template<>
constexpr int f<0>() { return 1; }


int main () {
  std::cout << f<5>();
  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles nicely with both g++ and clang. Very nice.
Now add `static` to the template function specialization:

```
template<>
constexpr static int f<0>() { return 1; }
```

then g++ 6.1 reacts with an error:

> 11 : error: explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class

and clang 3.8 too:

> 11 : error: explicit specialization has extraneous, inconsistent storage class 'static'

They look like in agreement. Very nice again.
Now, add `static` keyword also the template function general case:

g++ 6.1:

> 11 : error: explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class

clang 3.8 compiles with a warning:

> 11 : warning: explicit specialization cannot have a storage class

and clang result returns the correct answer.

Is this a bug in clang? If not, in which case does it make sense not to throw an error?

Comment: I say, this is an error. g++ is correct.

Comment: What do you mean is this a bug?  You were issued a diagnostic so there is something wrong with the code.  Most of the time you should use -Werror which will halt compilation.

Comment: @NathanOliver: what does the standard says ? Have you gone thorugh the standard ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as simple as [[dcl.stc]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.stc#1) (which goes as far back as C++98):

> A *storage-class-specifier* other than `thread_local` shall not be specified in an explicit specialization (14.7.3) or an explicit instantiation (14.7.2) directive.